# Could not load NIB in bundle :NSBundle

Tags: ios, viewcontroller, nib, nsbundle

I am trying to load a nib file from MainViewController but i get an exception which i mentioned below. I am not getting this exception regularly (1 out of fifty times). Check the exception below

Exception :

```
 Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/38ABE26C-F87E-49F1-9F29-E46E7ACDBD54/E2_IOS_App.app> (loaded)' with name 'NetWorkError'
```

the code i use to present this nib file is

```
NetWorkError *error=[[NetWorkError alloc]initWithNibName:@"NetWorkError" bundle:nil];
                    error.errorMessage=[details serverDownMessage];   // passing some message before presenting .
                    [self presentViewController:error animated:YES completion:nil];
```

i am using an iPad running with iOS 7.

People with similar issues where asked to check the nib name , check if the .xib is added to target, check if the .xib is added to copy bundle resource.But every thing is correct for me. what else might be the issue ??.

Comment: have the `view` property been connected properly to the view in IB?

Comment: I am able to load the .xib 49 out of 50 times

Comment: Unrelated, but you should seriously consider renaming your classes to reflect what they are, NetWorkError would be a good name for an actually error, NetworkErrorViewController is a good name for a viewController that displays a network error. Error is a common name for an NSError. Also if serverDownMessage is a property, use dot syntax, not method syntax. Poor naming conventions can sometimes lead to issues themselves, so it's good to keep good habits.

Comment: Since NetWorkError is a UIViewController, can you try loading it from the storyboard and see if you have similar issues? You may not have rigged up the file owner and such correctly (in that case you may just want to re create it).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `NSStringFromClass([NetWorkError class])` ?

Also you can try to exclude and add file to your project again / clean project / delete app from simulator.

Comment: it is actually running in device . I tried all those things . Will it be some memory related issue ??

Comment: hmmm, strange thing..

removing from device and renaming the file also have no influence?

Also some people mention that could be smth with internationalization [link](http://samwize.com/2012/11/22/warning-do-not-use-base-internationalization-in-ios-5/)